# Assign value from one variable to another new variable

Tags: r, variable-assignment

my data is here:

`x <- data.frame("Year" = c(1945,1945,1945,1946,1946,1946, 1947,1947,1947), "Age" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), "Value" = c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))`

I would like to assign the value from "year+1 and age +1" to a new variable. Ex. For the case with year =1945 and age=1, I would like to assign the value = 8 (from year = 1946, age =2 ) to the new variable.

My ideal result will be like this:
`x <- data.frame("Year" = c(1945,1945,1945,1946,1946,1946, 1947,1947,1947), "Age" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), "Value" = c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),"Year1moereandAge1more"= c(8,9,NA, 11, 12, NA, NA, NA,NA))`

Thank you for helping a beginner.

Comment: your result doesn't track with what you describe. your second value in the result column is year +1 but age +2. please clarify

Comment: @D.J row 2 has `Year = 1945, Age = 2`. If we look for the row with incremented year and age,  row 6 has `Year = 1946, Age = 3, value = 9`.  Hence row 2 gets `Year1moereandAge1more = 9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a modified self-join:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  transmute(Year = Year - 1, Age = Age - 1, Year1moereandAge1more = Value) %>%
  right_join(x) %>%
  arrange(Year, Age)
# Joining, by = c("Year", "Age")
#   Year Age Year1moereandAge1more Value
# 1 1945   1                     8     4
# 2 1945   2                     9     5
# 3 1945   3                    NA     6
# 4 1946   1                    11     7
# 5 1946   2                    12     8
# 6 1946   3                    NA     9
# 7 1947   1                    NA    10
# 8 1947   2                    NA    11
# 9 1947   3                    NA    12
```